# Robomongo: Connection error. Uninitialized Mongo scope

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, database

The connection opens successfully (with authentication). The Database and the collection are displayed. But if I open any shell I got this error:

> Connection error. Uninitialized mongo scope.

The connection with the Mongo.exe and Java-Driver works fine. What does the error message mean? How to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just removed the special character from the password and works now.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a bug in RoboMongo; if the password contains an *apostrophe*, then you can connect OK but you get this error when you try to run a query.

I have logged it as an issue with the RoboMongo team: https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/1300

Note: no other characters seem to cause this problem, only the apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions work if you have recently upgraded to Robo 3T v1.3 and trying to connect to an older MongoDB version like <3.0. Apparently, Robo 3T removed some of the support for older versions and you get the same "Uninitialized mongo scope" error. Reverting to Robo 3T v1.2 is the only solution to this one.

Comment: i am using robo 3t v1.3 with mongodb 4.2 but still facing the same issue

Comment: @dd619 Lately I m having problems with robo3t 1.3 as well. Especially with recent versions of mongodb and mongodb atlas. It is not getting enough development support I guess. You would better off with MongoDb Compass at this point. (If you cant afford to buy Studio 3T)

Comment: Well its started working today without doing anything.....I think this is issue from the robomongo only.

Answer (score -1):

This is not error message you need to `reauthenticate`( Remove connection and add new Connection) database connection.

Once you reauthenticate and connect with the database. All will work fine.